# How to get local time Android

Tags: android, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a String of a date and time in my app eg:- `2014-10-30T11:30:00` I want to convert this String into my local time which should look something like this
 `2014-10-30T11:30:00+05:30`. I cannot Manipulate the String as the server side conversion is done to do the addition and subtraction of the time. How do I add the +05:30 offset to my time?

How can I do it using the local time so that the server knows my locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

How to use given function :

convertDateStringFormat("2014-10-30T11:30:00","yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")

Here you have pass three parameter as :

```
1.strDate    : which is represent datetime string.
2.fromFormat : which is represent datetime format of your given datetime string.
3.toFormat   : which is represent datetime format which you wan to convert your given  datetime string. 

public String convertDateStringFormat(String strDate, String fromFormat, String toFormat){
   try{
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
       sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat.trim());
       return dateFormat2.format(sdf.parse(strDate));
    }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return "";
    }  
}
```

Comment: This would convert to UTC right? I want the local conversion

Comment: @iamstack,no it will convert to local and your given datetime convert UTC then it converted to local.

Comment: I tried your code but I get an exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-10-30 11:30:51" (at offset 10)

Comment: then your from and to format is "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss".

Comment: convertDateStringFormat("2014-10-30 11:30:51","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Comment: @iamstack,glad to help you can you please upvote ans ?

Comment: ANother doubt if you can help me with. What if I want to convert it back to the UTC?

Comment: Easy just set setTimeZone to dateFormat2 instead of sdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
  long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
  Log.d("Server time: ", timestamp);
  String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(timestamp * 1000));
  Log.d("Time: ", localTime);
```

Comment: how does this add the offset?

Comment: you can add offset like this Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
                Locale.getDefault());
        Date currentLocalTime = calendar.getTime();
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);